# Send Dropzone file.fullPath to Rails controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to extract the full path of the file that has been uploaded from dropping a folder into a Dropzone in Chrome. The file uploading and all other metadata is being transferred properly. I just want to pass along the full path of the file that is being uploaded as well.

I have attempted a lot to fix this problem, but still rather new especially to Javascript. These are my resources:

[Get uploaded file from Dropzone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22942106/get-uploaded-file-from-dropzone)

[Passing JQuery Datepicker Data to Rails Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13847871/passing-jquery-datepicker-data-to-rails-controller)

[Passing the variables from from jquery to rails controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11211433/passing-the-variables-from-from-jquery-to-rails-controller)

[How to pass variables from AJAX form into controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11842978/how-to-pass-variables-from-ajax-form-into-controller)

[Dropzone.js and full path for each file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200717/dropzone-js-and-full-path-for-each-file) (*which has no response*)

**These are my attempts:**

## **Uploads new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@parent, @upload], method: :post, html: { multipart: true, class: "dropzone", id: "upload-dropzone"}) do |f| %>

  <% if @upload.errors.any? %>
    <ul>
      <% @upload.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :full_path %>
  <%= javascript_tag do %>
    window.parent = '<%= @parent.id %>';
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

## **application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dropzone
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
// Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

// $(document).ready(function(){
//   var myDropzone = Dropzone.getElementById("upload-dropzone");
//   new Dropzone(myDropzone);
//   myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
//     formData.append('full_path', file.fullPath);
//   })
//   console.log(file.fullPath);
// })

// var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#upload-dropzone");
// document.querySelector("#upload-dropzone").classList.add("dropzone");
// var myDropzone = document.getElementById("upload-dropzone");
// Dropzone.myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData){
//   formData.append('full_path', file.fullPath);
// })

Dropzone.options.uploadDropzone = {

  accept: function(file, done){
    var fullPath = { full_path: file.fullPath };
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: { full_path: fullPath.full_path }
    });
  done();
  }
}
```

The application.js also has my other attempts at extracting the fullPath from the jQuery Dropzone element. In the uncommented function, I can access the full path in the javascript console with:

```
file.fullPath
```

I would like to access this in:

## **Uploads Controller**

```
def create
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:parent_id])
  # here is an attempt to create the upload with the file_path
  @upload = Upload.new(upload: params[:file], full_path: params[:full_path])
  if @upload.save!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json{ render json: @upload }
    end
  end
end
```

## **Routes.rb**

```
resources :parent do
  post 'uploads/new' => 'uploads#new'
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what worked:

adding to **application.js**

```
Dropzone.options.uploadDropzone = false;
```

adding to **upload.js**

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#upload-dropzone");
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
   formData.append("full_path", file.fullPath);
});
```

Comment: +1 but I didn't need to set `uploadDropzone` to `false` for this to work.  Your `sending` callback worked a charm for me.